# A div can't scroll when in div that has transform property

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/o802wv9q/

```
#d1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background:red;
    transform: rotateY(1deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(1deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(1deg);
}
#d2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:90px; height:90px;
    background:green;
    overflow:auto;
}
#d3 {
    width:50px; height:500px;
    background:blue;
}

<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2">
    <div id="d3"></div>
</div>
```

Move mouse to blue block and scroll, green block not scrolling, move to green block and scroll, it's ok. I remove the transform css property and in blue block to scroll, work well. I am test in chrome. What happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform` is changing the stacking index, to rectify this, you also need to translate on the z axis:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/o802wv9q/1/)

```
transform: rotateY(1deg)  translateZ(-1px);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(1deg)  translateZ(-1px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(1deg)  translateZ(-1px);
-o-transform: rotateY(1deg)  translateZ(-1px);
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to calculate translateZ value with rotateY? I set rotateY to 180deg, translateZ to -180px, not work.

Comment: @user1434702 - just set it to 1px